# How to open browser in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i'm doing  a project where i have to call a browser via my  android app, but when i call it, the app stops.

the code can be found here: https://github.com/coppetti/android-pulsometer

but for fast view, i have a "Pulsometro" class where

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
...
Browser browser = new Browser();
browser.callBrowser(beats);

return;
...
}
```

and a Browser class where:

```
public class Browser extends Activity{
     public  void callBrowser(int beats){
         String url = "http://www.higia.info/?q="+beats;
         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
         startActivity(i);

         return;
        }
}
```

There's a way to call a browser and my app doesn't breaks?

Comment: Note: you don't need a `return;` at the end of a method in java.

Comment: Yes, i tried returning to see if works or not.. even without it, breaks...

Comment: We'll need a stacktrace (from the logcat), to analyse "breaks"...

Comment: logcat output can be found here: http://pastie.org/8306098

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onOpenWebBrowser(View v)
{
Intent webPageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
webPageIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in/"));

try {
          startActivity(webPageIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not just randomly choose superclasses. Do not just create some subclass of `Activity` and expect it to work.

Move your `callBrowser()` method into some real `Activity` implementation, and get rid of `Browser` entirely.

Or, remove the superclass from `Browser`, have `callBrowser()` take a `Context` as a parameter, and call `startActivity()` on that `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this class. Call the `callBrowser` method and give it and `Activity` for the `context` parameter.

```
public class Browser{
 public  void callBrowser(Context context, int beats){
     String url = "http://www.higia.info/?q="+beats;
     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
     context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or as Commonsware suggested, drop `Browser` altogether and create a method in a real `Activity`. Or really, if that's all you do in the callBrowser method, don't even create a new method, the code is too simple.